# Can I use Guymager tool to create image of Android Phone?

Tags: android, sd-card, disk-image

I wish to create bit-by-bit images of Android phone and it's SD card. So far I have learnt to create dd images. But I am unable to use them as they are just raw images. I wish to use this `Guymager` tool to create forensic images of the Phone and the SD card. Please tell me how should I proceed?